# Is it possible to calculate log10 x without using log?

Tags: functions, logarithms

Is it possible to calculate $\log_{10} x$ without using $\log_{10}$? I'm interested because I'm working with a framework that has some simple functions, but `log` is not one of them.

The specific platform is capable of doing addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. I can write a formula of a finite, predefined length; e.g. `while` loops or `for` loops that continue indefinitely are not available. It's a black-box project with an interface capable of creating formulas, so basically, I need to write the expression to calculate $\log_{10} x$ in one line, and I can't write my own method or something to do more dynamic calculations.

An approximation of $\log_{10} x$ is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Could you flesh out your question to give the context, what functions you dispose of, what base the logarithm has, what $x$ is?

Comment: You could use a taylor series for the logarithm to get an approximation. In that case you would only need addition, multiplication and division.

Comment: It depends on the accuracy you need and of the space you have. A very rough solution could be to register some values of the logarithm and use recursion to fall back to one of them, by successive multiplications or divisions by $2$.

Comment: @Raskolnikov the base is 10. x is something I can calculate with addition/multiplication.

Comment: maybe use a Taylor series?

Comment: The Taylor Series given has a small radius of convergence... I recommend a Pade Approximation instead. Perhaps calculate a Pade Expression of order 5 or so? I think it should work a lot better. From personal experience, I recommend calculating the Pade Approximation for $\ln(1+x)$ and then substitute $z = x-1$ to get an expression for $\ln(z)$. Then use a stored value of $\ln(10)$ and divide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a Taylor polynomial to first roughly compute $\ln n$.
$$\ln n\approx0+\dfrac{1}{1!}(n-1)+\dfrac{(\frac{-1}{n^2})}{2!}(n-1)^2+\dfrac{(\frac{2}{n^3})}{3!}(n-1)^3+\dfrac{(\frac{-6}{n^4})}{4!}(n-1)^4+\dfrac{(\frac{24}{n^5})}{5!}(n-1)^5$$
Then use the fact that $\ln 10 \approx2.302585092994046$, so divide $\ln n$ by that to get $\log_{10} n$

Comment: Why does the dividend (over the factorial part of the series) go from using `n` to using `x`?

Comment: oops.. I'll correct my mistake

Comment: Thanks. I feel like this is the easiest to understand, and useful answer in my case, as I need to write a simple equation in the form $\log_{10} x = $... and not introduce new variables.

Comment: I think this taylor series only converges if $n \leq 2$.

Comment: @flawr, tho argument reduction ($\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$) will actually allow you to squeeze out answers from it if needed.

Comment: That's not a Taylor polynomial (or a polynomial at all). I think you want to get rid of all the $n^i$ denominators (the derivative needs to be *evaluated* at the expansion point).

Comment: @MarkDickinson You're correct. I might edit, but it's an old post. If you want to change it, go ahead.

Comment: @Mastrem: Right, I only noticed because it was [linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48839613/calculate-lnx-in-python-without-importing-math) from StackOverflow, where some poor soul was trying to use this expression to implement their own log.

Answer (score 9):

Write $x=a\times 10^b$ with $0<a<1$. So, $$\log_{10}x=b+\log_{10}(a)=b+\frac{\log (a)}{\log (10)}$$ Now, use the very fast convergent series expansion $$\log\Big(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\Big)=2\Big(\frac{x}{1}+\frac{x^3}{3}++\frac{x^5}{5}+\cdots\Big)$$ using $a=\frac{1+x}{1-x}$ that is to say $x=\frac{a-1}{a+1}$ and you know that $\log(10)\approx 2.30259$.

Comment: Can you please explain a little more verbosely what it is you are doing? What is the first premise `(x = a * 10^b ...)`?

Comment: Since we speak about $\log_{10}(x)$, we know that $\log_{10}(10^b)=b$. So, we isolate this term first and just focus on $a$ that is to say the mantissa.

Comment: So, if I have understood this correctly, this requires me to first refactor `x` into the product of `a` which is a number between 0 and 1, and `10^b`, where `b` is unknown. Am I correct, and how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Suppose that $x>1$, then count the number of times you need to divide it by $10$ until the result of the division is $<1$; this gives $b$. If $x<1$, count the number of times you need tomultiply it by $10$ until the result of the multiplication is $>1$; this gives $b+1$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. So I take it it is not possible to rewrite your answer in the form $\log_{10} x = $... at least not without introducing the new variable `b`. Correct?

Answer (score 7):

The [CORDIC algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) may help here (used by most calculators working in BCD in the old days because requiring only additions and shifts).

It uses an array $\rm{L}$ of precalculated logarithms in base $10$ ($\log$ means $\log_{10}$ here) and
$x$ will be supposed written using digits (with a decimal point) :

```
L= [log(2), log(1.1), log(1.01), ... , log(1.000001)];
```

The relation
$\;\displaystyle \log(x) = \log\left(x\,10^{−n}\right) + n\;\;$
is used to get all positive real values $x$ in the range $(1,10]\;$ ($n$ is the number of shifts of the decimal points required for this purpose, $10^{−n}$ really means "right-shift of $n$" for $n>0$).

The algorithm may then be applied to $\;x\mapsto x\,10^{−n}$ :

```
k= 0; y= 0; p= 1;  //p is the partial product
while (k <= 6)
{
   while (x >= p+p*10^(-k))
   {
      y= y+L[k];       // L[k] = log(1+10^{-k})
      p= p+p*10^(-k);
   }
   k= k+1;
}
return y;
```

The idea is that for 
$$x=(1+1)^{n_0}\,(1+10^{-1})^{n_1}\,(1+10^{-2})^{n_2}\cdots (1+10^{-6})^{n_6}(1+\epsilon)$$
we will get
$$\log(x)=n_0\log(1+1)+n_1\log(1+10^{-1})+\cdots+n_6\log(1+10^{-6})$$
and the precision should be near $7$ digits with the upperbound $6$ (more terms means more precision).

Comment: NB. replacing the return value $y$ by $\;y+\log(e)\,(x/p-1)\;$ would give nearly $13$ digits precision (If division and multiplication are allowed...)

Answer (score 4):

Many platforms will at least have a function for the natural logarithm ($\ln$).

Note that $\log_{10}(x) = \ln(x)/\ln(10)$.

Comment: This is unfortunately not the case with the platform I'm working with. But I guess I can get an approximation of `ln x` using Mastrem's answer and use what you proposed.

Answer (score 3):

There also exists an approximation of the logarithm from the arithmetric-geometric mean:

$$\ln x\approx\frac{\pi}{2M_{AG}(1,\frac{4}{s})}-m\ln(2)$$ where $s=2^m.x>2^\frac{p}{2}$ and error is about $\frac{\ln x}{2^p}$

This is interesting because this mean converges quickly, so you can get a better approximation than with by using Taylor series at least for general numbers. All you need to have is a definition of constants $\pi$ and $ln(2)$ with good precision.

You do not need to know $p$ in practice, this is just to show the order of precision obtained. $2^m$ is also easy to compute because it is a simple integer shift, the bigger the $m$ you choose, the bigger precision you get. I tested with $m=31$ just to stay within 32 bits types, and I got more than 10 exact decimals for $\ln x$.

And $M_{AG}$ can be calculated easily in a simple for loop, in general for usual floats double precision, it converges in less than 10 steps.

To get $\log_{10}(x)$ just divide the result by another constant $\ln(10)$.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the formula posted above by Mastrem, but it works good enough only when n is close to 1. When n is not close to 1, then that formula gives a result with big error, and when n is a big number that formula is not applicable at all.

What to do? When n is a big number you can use the property of log, which states that
$$log_a(b)^c = c \; log_a (b) $$

If you have to find ln n, and n is a big number, then you must first take 10 times  (just 10 is enough for any big number) the square root of n. Let us name this new number $\alpha$:

$$\alpha = \sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(\sqrt(n))))))))))$$
(using the standard denomination for square root function in many programs)

so,

$$n = ((((((((((\alpha)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2$$

and we can write:
$$ln \,n = ln((((((((((\alpha)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2)^2$$

an using the log property explained above:
$$ln \,n = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\, ln (\alpha) = 1024\, ln \,(\alpha) $$

where $\alpha$ will be always very close to 1, and the formula of Mastrem above can be used.

Comment: Nice to note! Welcome to Math SE by the way! +1!

Answer (score 0):

Let x = 1545 and proceed as follows:

1. Divide x by base 10 until x becomes smaller than base 10.
   1545/10 = 154.5
   154.5 / 10 = 15.45
   15.45 / 10 = 1.545
   As we divide 3 times the value of x by 10, the whole digit of our logarithm will be 3.
2. Raise x to the tenth power:
   1.545 ^ 10 = 77.4969905 ...
3. Repeat the procedures from step 1.

As we divide only 1 time, the next digit of our logarithm will be 1.

4. Repeat step 2.

7.74969905 ... ^ 10 = 781.354.964,875286221 ...

5. Repeat step 1.

Since we divide x by 10 by 8 times, the next digit in our log will be 8.

And so on, as many digits as you want.